# iOS - Best way to save a list of user's favourite objects in memory

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, save, nsuserdefaults

I am working on an app that display photos of buildings along with some information about them. The photos are jpegs that all come in the app bundle, and the *Building* objects associated with them have a few properties such as name, address, and of course, a photos array. I'm loading the *Building* objects from a plist when the app launches. Everything's pretty straight forward, except that when the user scrolls through the images of buildings they have the option to add the ones they like to a favourite's list for viewing later.

Originally I was going to save each *Building* object they favorited using Core Data, but now that I think about it it seems a little redundant because all of the *Building* objects are already loaded from the plist. When the user is scrolling through the images of each building the photos have to display an indication of weather that building has been added to the favourite's list yet, which means I'll have to continuously compare an array of objects taken from CoreData with an array of objects loaded from a plist, which seems like it could be a memory wasting task.

I was wondering if, as an alternative to CoreData, I could add a unique ID property to the *Building* object and store it in the plist with them. Then when the user adds a *Building* to their favourites list I can just add it's UID to an array in NSUSerDefaults and make the comparison that way. Does that seem like a sensible way to tackle this?

Comment: Yes, NSUserDefaults would work perfectly as you described.

Answer (score 1):

Storing data like this in `NSUserDefaults` is a really bad habit to get into. Save user preferences in `NSUserDefaults`, not sets of data.

Much better idea is to save the user's favorites in a file in the Documents folder. If you've added an "ID property" to your Building object, you can maintain an array of selected IDs. That array can be saved to and read from disk with:

```
NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *myFile = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myFavs"];
```

and then

```
// save the array contents to file named "myFavs"
[a writeToFile:myFile atomically:YES];
```

or

```
// read the saved array when you launch the app
NSArray *b = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:myFile];
```

Of course, you'll want to add error handling, but this is a much, much better idea than stuffing an array into NSUserDefaults.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps using CoreData for favourites is OK, although, consider using Sets  which stores distinct values of the same type in a collection with no defined ordering

Answer (score 0):

Assumptions: 
- Your buildings data isn't coming from a dynamic/external source
- You don't have a massive amount of data.

why not add a property to the buildings to flag it as a favorite and store that local when the app goes to the background. (NSUserDefaults or document directory as plist)?. Then in future app loads use the local one that has the flags.

That way you don't need an additional data structure to store identifiers and a list of favorites.

CoreData seems like overkill for the problem you're describing.